# Can anybody explain this command

Tags: c, bluetooth, embedded, dbus

Here I want to know about dbus-send command in brief

I want to know how we can use this and how this command call automatically functions of other c files.

Here I put one example which is used in Bluetooth pairing and unpairing. please Explain me

```
dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.bluez  $BT_ADAPTER org.bluez.Adapter.RemoveDevice objpath:$BT_ADAPTER/dev_$BD_ADDR_XX
```

Here BT_ADAPTER is Blue adapter like: `/org/bluez/1536/hci0`
     BD_ADDR_XX is Bluetooth address: `XX_XX_XX_XX_XX_XX`

Here I know about --system --print-reply options and all others options but how its works with source files I do not know.

So Anybody please can Explain me hows this command call and use functions from C source files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check out dbus document and there's a long way to go.

http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/IntroductionToDBus

What exactly do you want? Writing a dbus service or a client?

Must you write in C, because python would be a far better choice.
http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-python/doc/tutorial.html

============================

First, a dbus service connects to dbus-daemon and ask for a service address(in your case org.bluez).
Then it registers different interface at different object paths, each interface contains some method calls/signals for users to use.

In your case:

- Dbus daemon process(dbus-daemon --system) is started.
- Bluez daemon process started and ask dbus-daemon for "org.bluez" service address
- Bluez daemon process register some interfaces at /org/bluez/{process pid}/{bluetooth controller name} (check bluez source code, in doc directory)
- When you call dbus-send command, the command line tool will connect to dbus-daemon, sending the service address(-dest), object path(/org/bluez/1536/hci0), interface name, the method you call(
  org.bluez.Adapter.RemoveDevice) and parameters.
- Dbus-daemon resend it to bluez

============================

Dbus daemon doesn't get service address or method calls.
It's you or client process who tells it the service address and method-call names.

DBus daemon will then send target service process a data packet contains obj-path, interface/method name and parameters in its own format(through a unix local socket file).

Target service process then unpacks the packet, get the object-path, interface and etc. , decide what it should do. That's not automatically done and you need to write your own code to handle it(method dispatch or so), or use some library like dbus-glib/gdbus.

============================

I checked source code of Bluez-4.98. It uses gdbus for method dispatch.

Take "CreateDevice" for example.

in src/adapter.c, there's such a struct

```
static GDBusMethodTable adapter_methods[] = {
{ "GetProperties",  "", "a{sv}",get_properties      },
{ "SetProperty",    "sv",   "", set_property,
                    G_DBUS_METHOD_FLAG_ASYNC},
{ "RequestSession", "", "", request_session,
                    G_DBUS_METHOD_FLAG_ASYNC},
{ "ReleaseSession", "", "", release_session     },
{ "StartDiscovery", "", "", adapter_start_discovery },
{ "StopDiscovery",  "", "", adapter_stop_discovery,
                    G_DBUS_METHOD_FLAG_ASYNC},
{ "ListDevices",    "", "ao",   list_devices,
                    G_DBUS_METHOD_FLAG_DEPRECATED},
{ "CreateDevice",   "s",    "o",    create_device,
                    G_DBUS_METHOD_FLAG_ASYNC},
{ "CreatePairedDevice", "sos",  "o",    create_paired_device,
                    G_DBUS_METHOD_FLAG_ASYNC},
{ "CancelDeviceCreation","s",   "", cancel_device_creation,
                    G_DBUS_METHOD_FLAG_ASYNC},
{ "RemoveDevice",   "o",    "", remove_device,
                    G_DBUS_METHOD_FLAG_ASYNC},
{ "FindDevice",     "s",    "o",    find_device     },
{ "RegisterAgent",  "os",   "", register_agent      },
{ "UnregisterAgent",    "o",    "", unregister_agent    },
{ }
};
```

which means CreateDevice Method call will eventually calls create_device function.

And in line 2418

```
    if (!g_dbus_register_interface(conn, path, ADAPTER_INTERFACE,
                adapter_methods, adapter_signals, NULL,
                adapter, adapter_free)) {
    error("Adapter interface init failed on path %s", path);
    adapter_free(adapter);
    return NULL;
}
```

you register the interface ADAPTER_INTERFACE("org.bluez.Adapter") with all its methods and signals.

Then all the underlying dbus event monitor and method dispatch will be handled by gdbus(after init dbus connection and event handling in src/main.c). When some client calls org.bluez.Adapter.CreateDevice, it eventually get into function create_device at src/adapter.c line 1468.

```
static DBusMessage *create_device(DBusConnection *conn,
                DBusMessage *msg, void *data)
{
struct btd_adapter *adapter = data;
struct btd_device *device;
const gchar *address;
DBusMessage *reply;
int err;

if (dbus_message_get_args(msg, NULL, DBUS_TYPE_STRING, &address,
                    DBUS_TYPE_INVALID) == FALSE)
    return btd_error_invalid_args(msg);

if (check_address(address) < 0)
    return btd_error_invalid_args(msg);

if (!adapter->up)
    return btd_error_not_ready(msg);

if (adapter_find_device(adapter, address))
    return btd_error_already_exists(msg);

DBG("%s", address);
......
```

I'm not familiar with gdbus and if you want to dig deeper I suggest you to check the official website: http://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/gdbus-convenience.html

============================

lol

Then you just need to check out 'test' directory of bluez source code.

There are both python and C examples.

Also, bluez dbus interface changed a lot from 3.XX to 4.XX, so check out the right version.

Comment: i want to know about how its call object path and destination options .Means i want to know in above example how org.bluez.Adapter.RemoveDevice call?

Comment: First, a dbus service connects to dbus-daemon and ask for an address(in your case org.bluez).

Comment: Thanks a lot for this Explanation. but one thing is in Confusion. How Dbus daemon Process get service Address and Method call which is in source code. how this automatically call there.? there is any dbus related source file which initiate this method (org.Bluez.Adapter.RemoveDevice)?

Comment: =======================Sorry, too long

Comment: Thanks a lot. But i am asking not this thing. i asked about how this method call through dbus. because i seen source code of bluez there is method name Remove Device, CreatePairedDevice and CreateDevice. i want to know how these methods calls through dbus-deamon.

Comment: Ok i got it. I have Glib and Dbus libraries. so this code decides what will happen ahed?

Comment: Are u der.Please can u assist me on above my confusion

Comment: Which side are you asking, client side or server side?

Comment: Client Side i am asking . i have bluetooth device and try to connect my bluetooth with remote device